# Displaying a Value from a Variable - API (Magento)

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I have an API script which is retrieving product data from the Magento API.

[image]

This is then displayed with the line `print_r($productsList)`, which displays as so:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to echo only one of those values. I've tried things such as:

`echo $productsList['sku']` and `print_r(&productsList['sku'])`

But nothing works. I assume this is because this is a variable and not an array. Is there any way of doing this? Or is the data being brought back from the Magento API in "one piece" which can't be split?

Full script is below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
$callbackUrl = "xxx";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'https://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'xxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxx';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();
    
    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($requestToken);echo '</pre>';
        //exit;
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products/?order=entity_id&filter[0][attribute]=sku&filter[0][in][0]=product1";
        //echo $resourceUrl;
        //exit;
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'));
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    echo '<pre>';print_r($e);echo '</pre>';
}

print_r($productsList);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it

```
echo $productsList->215->sku
```

In your case

Comment: 215 needed to be encapsulated within brackets: `echo $productList->{215}->sku;`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is an object and not a standard array.

Try `echo $productsList->sku;`

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work as it brought back a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the second option in json_decode to true. That will instruct the function to return an associative array.

```
$productList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse(), true);
```

Comment: This didn't work when using `echo $productsList['sku']`, am I possibly referencing the array incorrectly? Thank you.

Comment: Yes this works fine whilst having the extra `true` added.

Comment: Then echo $productsList[215]['sku']; should also work.

Answer (score 0):

> This will always  work for converting json object to array.

```
$productList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse(), true);
```

> But you can try this one also

```
$productList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse(), 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the same answer as what was given by Juri Salminen earlier. I have implemented this but I still cannot echo the value using `echo $productList['sku']` for example.